# Delete account using Smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I want to delete account via Smack. There is [method](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/smack-extensions/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/iqregister/AccountManager.java#L317) to delete the currently logged-in account from the server. But I need to delete another account when I logged with admin account.

I can create accounts with:

```
accountManager.createAccount(username, password);
```

But can't find method for deletion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you:

- Create a new connection and log in as the account to be deleted
- Create a new AccountManager for that connection
- Delete the account using that AccountManager.

This requires you to know the password of the target account to be deleted.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to change the other user's password, while logged in with an administrator account.

Answer (score -1):

AccountManager has function to delete the account

```
https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/iqregister/AccountManager.html#deleteAccount()
```

After you delete the account, wait for sometime(at least 10 mins). XMPP server takes time to sync.

Comment: Function "deletes the currently logged-in account from the server". I need to delete another account.

Comment: which xmpp server you are using?

Comment: Smack API deletes logged in user only. If you want to remove user from admin account, I think you will have to go to protocol level(http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#delete-user)